# How to iterate visible rows alone using UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

when i iterate this below webtable,i am getting row count as 3(with hidden row).
but i can see only 2 rows in my application.
i can get row count with help of descriptive programming,but i want to iterate only the rows which are visible.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="show">Name</tr>
  <tr class="hide">Ticket</tr>
  <tr class="show">city</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

i have tried this below code,but its displays hidden row text as well,

```
for i=1 to rowcount
  print oWebtable.getcelldata(i,2)
next
```

**Actual Output**-
Name,
Ticket,
city

**expecting output**-
Name,
city

Answer (score 3):

UFT has no way knowledge of your `show/hide` class names. If you want to filter out some rows you need to do it yourself.

```
Set desc = Description.Create()
desc("html tag").Value = "TR"
desc("class").Value = "show"

Set cells = oWebtable.ChildObjects(desc)
Print "Count: " & cells.Count
For i = 0 To cells.Count - 1
    Print i & ": " & cells(i).GetROProperty("inner_text")
Next
```

Note that I had to add `TD` elements to your table in order for this to work since it's [invalid HTML to have text in a `TR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) element.